# Remove sticky header after scrolling to some point

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to remove the sticky `css` from the header after it reaches 300px from top but with `css` I am unable to do so and I have 0 `jquery` knowledge.

Is it possible from css alone?

Here's my [sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/rahulxdd/uy11f99k/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've added this to a jsfiddle for you, you would need to use jquery to get this to work.

Please see:
https://jsfiddle.net/975zff02/

```
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(e) {
    if($(this).scrollTop()>300){
      $('.header').fadeOut(); // Fading out the button on scroll after 300px
    }
    else{
      $('.header').fadeIn(); // Fading in the button on scroll if less than 300px
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I just came across an issue with this approach. When we scroll at the point where it will fade away(disappear) it starts blinking. Can we stop it?

Comment: The issue is because you are using position:sticky on the header. Change this to position:fixed; top:0; width:100%; and this will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need jQuery. You can just do this with javascript.

You can apply a class; `.header` for example, to your  and use the following pure js:

```
var header = document.querySelector('.header');
var isHeaderHidden = false;

function onScroll() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > 300 && !isHeaderHidden) {
    header.style.opacity = "0";
    isHeaderHidden = true;
  } else if (window.pageYOffset <= 300 && isHeaderHidden) {
    header.style.opacity = "1";
    isHeaderHidden = false;
  }
}

var debouncedOnScroll = debounce(onScroll, 50);
window.addEventListener('scroll', debouncedOnScroll);

function debounce(fn, delay) {
  var timer = null;

  return function() {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      fn.apply(context, args);
    }, delay);
  };
}
```

Simply explained:

- `var header = document.querySelector('.header');`: This line retrieves the first element with the class "header" in the document and assigns it to the variable `header`,
- `var isHeaderHidden = false;`: This line initializes the variable `isHeaderHidden` to `false`, which is used later to keep track of whether the `.header` element is currently hidden.
- `function onScroll() {...}`: This function is called whenever the window is scrolled. It checks whether the scroll position is greater than 300 pixels and whether the header is currently visible. If both conditions are true, it hides the header by setting its `opacity` property to 0 and sets `isHeaderHidden` to `true`. If the scroll position is less than or equal to 300 pixels and the header is currently hidden, it shows the header by setting its `opacity` property to 1 and sets `isHeaderHidden` to `false`.
- `var debouncedOnScroll = debounce(onScroll, 50);`: This line creates a new debounced function by calling the `debounce` function with `onScroll` as the first argument and `50` as the second argument. The resulting function is assigned to the variable `debouncedOnScroll`.
- `window.addEventListener('scroll', debouncedOnScroll);`: This line attaches the `debouncedOnScroll` function to the scroll event of the window object. Whenever the window is scrolled, the `debouncedOnScroll` function is called.
- `function debounce(fn, delay) {...}`: This is a utility function that takes a function and a delay time as arguments and returns a new debounced function. The returned function delays the execution of the original function by the specified delay time, and if the function is called again during the delay period, the delay time is reset. This helps to prevent the original function from being called too frequently.

See my jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/UwGod/p5rzbq4y/3/